# Why does dynamic binding fail when using interface inheritance?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, inheritance, dynamic, interface

In C#, please does anyone know why I can't do the following? (specifically the line marked 'NOT fine!' below)

```
interface A
{
    void Add(dynamic entity);
}

interface B : A {}

class C : B
{
    public void Add(dynamic entity)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(entity);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new C();
        dynamic x = 23;
        b.Add(23);        // fine
        b.Add((int)x);    // fine
        (b as A).Add(x);  // fine
        //b.Add(x);       // NOT fine!
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no problems if the call isn't dynamically-bound, or if I explicitly cast to the interface at the root of the hierarchy, but the dynamically-bound call gives me:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: No overload for method 'Add' takes '1' arguments
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , B , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Stuart\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSharp Testbed\Program.cs:line 218
```

Comment: By the way, the last call fails even without a diamond inheritance.

Comment: @YuriyGuts: So much for a minimal compileable example eh? :) Ok, simplifying the question in that case.

Comment: +1 - It might also be good to note that `b.Add((int)x)` works.

Comment: This might be because of performance. If this where possible the run-time should always check out all interfaces that are implemented by the `class` or `interface` just to see if there are better matches for the call. normally most of this work will be done during compile.

Comment: @Jan-Peter Vos: Thanks! Certainly seems plausible. Sounds like the sort of thing which might be in the language specification actually, just going to have a look.

Comment: Looking on Microsoft Connect it's filed as a bug -
[Dynamic runtime fails to find method from a base interface during runtime](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597276/dynamic-runtime-fails-to-find-iset-t-contains-during-runtime)

Comment: @Luke Forder: Aha! That would seem to be the problem then :) Very good spot - if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Wayback machine link to the Microsoft Connect article: https://web.archive.org/web/20160131194922/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597276/dynamic-runtime-fails-to-find-iset-t-contains-during-runtime

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking on Microsoft Connect it's filed as a bug - [Dynamic runtime fails to find method from a base interface during runtime](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597276/dynamic-runtime-fails-to-find-iset-t-contains-during-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the multiple layers of interface inheritance are doing in the passing of a dynamic type variable. It's definitely tripping up the run time binding.

At this point if you're looking to get it to work a possible workaround is:

```
dynamic x = 23;
b.Add((object)x);

dynamic y = "Hello, World!";
b.Add((object)y);
```

Since dynamic is seen as object by the IL, so casting everything explicitly to type object will get this to work for you.

Comment: To the intermediate code, type dynamic is really just seen as type object. So, for this case at least, cast the dynamic as type object because the two are functionally equivalent for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: The question isn't about how to make it work, the question is _why doesn't it work_.

Comment: @oleksii: Although I was initially surprised by this, it does actually seem to work (even when I change `C.Add` to do something more interesting with `entity`). My understanding is that the cast to `object` forces the binding to be done at compile-time, but that within the function `entity` is still dynamically-typed. So this is yet another way of making the call statically-bound -> the case for which I said "I have absolutely no problems". Unfortunately, it still doesn't explain why I have problems in the dynamic-binding case.

Comment: @BradRem: Thanks for the additional workaround. I'm still curious as to what the problem is though.